# Inverted right triangle using while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I need to print this triangle using while loop :

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

My code is :

```
int a=0;
StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
str.append("*");
while(a<=5){
    System.out.println(str);
    str.append("*");
    a=a+1;
}
```

And its output is :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) So, what have you tried to solve the problem? What research have you done? What approaches occur to you?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: *(I've fixed the formatting for you on this occasion.)*

Comment: Quick tip: your `while` loop needs to count *backwards*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for fixing :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this backwards. You should start your string builder like '*****' and then replace (not append) the start with a space character. Here is an alternative using the method [setCharAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-):

```
public class TrianglePrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDescendingTriangle(5);
    }

    private static void printDescendingTriangle(final int a) {
        StringBuilder str = initialStringBuilder(a);
        int i = 0;

        while(i < a){
            System.out.println(str);
            str.setCharAt(i,' ');  // here I'm replacing the '*' with a space ' ' character
            i++;
        }
    }

    // To initialize the StringBuilder with the ***** characters with the specified length
    private static StringBuilder initialStringBuilder(int a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a);

        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++){
            sb.append("*");
        }
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```